# How to import Javascript into other javascript?

Tags: javascript, import

I want to use `import` in Javascript, but I cannot get it to work (Firefox 65.0.2 on Fedora 28).

I have this in my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="js/App.js" type="module"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">        
            $(function() {
                application = new App(true);
            });
        </script>
   </head>
</html>
```

and in my `js/App.js`:

```
import "js/Helpers.js"
class App {
    constructor(needsLogin) {
    }
}
```

with `js/Helpers.js` being

```
class Helpers {
}
```

but, when run, I get this error:

> ReferenceError: App is not defined

I tried adding `import` above the `new App()` call, but that gives me

> SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

How can I import `Helpers.js` in my `App.js` ?

Comment: in short, browsers don't support this yet.  You need to use a tool like webpack and babel to make this work.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes, but this says otherwise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Sorry, you are using the native way of loading.  Yes this works, but you need to make sure the module you want to import is being exported.